# calculating delta incorrectly

Tags: c++, c, delta

I am trying to calculate the delta in milliseconds with something like this:

```
int olddelta = 0;
    int delta = 0;
    const clock_t begin_time = clock();
    while (true) {
        olddelta=delta;
        delta=clock()-olddelta;
        cout<<delta<<endl;
}
```

however this is not working as the delta is definitely not over 4000, and it seems to get progressively higher. What have i done incorrectly?

Comment: What is it you're *trying* to do in the first place? Is `delta` supposed to be *per iteration* or accumulated over the life of the while-loop which is infinite). I *think* you're trying the former of those if you are expecting similar numbers with each iteration, and if so, this is just the wrong algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `clock()`, you need to divide it by [`CLOCKS_PER_SEC`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/) to obtain the result expressed in seconds. To get fractions, cast `clock()` to `double` before the division:

```
double olddelta = 0;
double delta = 0;
const double begin_time = clock();
while (true) {
    olddelta = delta;
    delta=clock()-olddelta;
    cout << (delta/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;
}
```

If you want to measure the time of a single iteration, change the loop as follows:

```
double olddelta = 0;
double delta = 0;
const double begin_time = clock();
while (true) {
    double now = clock();
    delta = now - begin_time;
    cout << (delta/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;
    begin_time = now;
}
```

Comment: This will change the display, to be sure, but something seems "odd" with the OP's surprise that this causes the progressively higher output it emits.

Comment: @WhozCraig I doubt that the OP is surprised by the numbers getting higher, only by the numbers getting higher by so much. 4000 seems like a large number or like a small number if one does not know what it means. My physics teacher used to jokingly ask if three hairs is too much or too little, and his answer was that if it's on the top of one's head, it's too little, and if it's in a bowl of one's soup, that's way too many ;-)

Comment: following your advice I still get an output that gets progressively higher, ex 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. Additionally is greater than one second a ridiculously high amount of time to execute such a simple while loop as the one above?

Comment: @user2673108 Your math is somewhat strange, because you store the `begin_time`, but never use it. If you want to measure the time of a single iteration, change the loop body as shown in the edited answer.

Comment: Love the hair-analogy, but as I suspected, there seems to be an expectation for something different. I *think* he's looking for a per-iteration delta, but again, without confirmation from the OP that continues to be speculation on my part, further supported by their continued surprise of their increasing values. Edit: +1. You pretty much covered the whole gambit now.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think you're right, OP's follow-up comment convinced me that he was looking for a different kind of output. I put my best guess into an edit - let's see what comes out of it.

Comment: My apologies I didn't realise that I hadn't mentioned that I wanted a per iteration delta, additionally just to be nitpicky but there is no need to redeclare now through every iteration, why not use old delta? Additionally even though I am pretty sure about this but if one wanted delta in millisecond then one would not divide it by clocks per time? Thank you for your help.